# Binary '==': no operator found - TCP Socket SFML

Tags: c++, networking, sfml

I'm trying to loop through a `std::list<sf::TcpSocket> clients` and delete the disconnected ones from `sf::SocketSelector` and from the list itself.
When trying to delete the client from the list, using an iterator, I keep getting a "binary '==' no operator found" error.
This is the part of the code where the error is triggered from:

```
std::list<sf::TcpSocket> clients;
std::list<sf::TcpSocket>::iterator i;

for (auto i = clients.begin(); i != clients.end();)
{
    if (selector.isReady(*i))
    {
        sf::Socket::Status status = i->receive(dummy, 1, received);
        if (status != sf::Socket::Done)
        {
            if (status == sf::Socket::Disconnected)
            {
                selector.remove(*i);
                clients.remove(*i);  // this causes the error
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: something wrong with `i = clients.erase(i);` ?

Comment: and it seems that  "i" inside the loop shadows "i" declared just before the loop, in other words "i" you declared right before the loop would not be modified by the loop

Comment: @AndrewKashpur yeah, you're right. I've also modified the loop having `auto i = std::begin(clients)` before the loop and then a `while (i != clients.end())`. Sorry, but I really struggle with iterators as I don't use them that often

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the object with its iterator, you already have it:

```
std::list<sf::TcpSocket> clients;
std::list<sf::TcpSocket>::iterator i;

for (auto i = clients.begin(); i != clients.end();)
{
    if (selector.isReady(*i))
    {
        sf::Socket::Status status = i->receive(dummy, 1, received);
        if (status != sf::Socket::Done)
        {
            if (status == sf::Socket::Disconnected)
            {
                selector.remove(*i);
                i = clients.erase(i); // Properly update the iterator
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ++i;
        }
    }
}
```